# Will Dispatchers.Main inside Work Manager blocks User Main thread?

Tags: android, multithreading, kotlin, kotlin-coroutines, android-workmanager

I created a class for worker, inside worker class I need to have api call and save the api response in room database. Before api call, I will check for the connectivity. For that I referred to this article
https://medium.com/@alexzaitsev/android-viewmodel-check-network-connectivity-state-7c028a017cd4

im using this connectivity in multiple places of my application, so im reusing it inside MyWorker class.

My worker looks like below:

```
class MyWorker(private val context: Context, parameters: WorkerParameters) :
    Worker(context, parameters) {

    lateinit var connectionLiveData: ConnectionLiveData
    override fun doWork(): Result {
         connectionLiveData = ConnectionLiveData(applicationContext)
            
            GlobalScope.launch(Dispatchers.Main) {
                
                connectionLiveData.observeForever { isConnected ->
                    isConnected?.let {
                Api.enqueue(object : Callback<Response> {
                override fun onFailure(call: Call<Response>, t: Throwable) {
                    t.printStackTrace()
                }

                override fun onResponse(call: Call<Response>, response: Response<Response>) {
                    if (response.isSuccessful) {
                       // save in db
                    }
                }               
                }
    
                }
            }
    }

}
```

I'm using this api call, so that user can initiate this api call and can navigate to other fragments or activity. Meanwhile, it will update the db in background without disturbing the user.

My question is, from my knowledge I know "Worker" will run in background. And "Dispatchers.Main" will run in Main thread.

If I use "Dispatchers.Main" inside "Worker", then my api call will happen in Main thread? If it runs in main thread, then my usage of worker is of no use? I'm using "Dispatchers.Main" to check the network, so it is not allowing me to use "Dispatchers.IO"(becoz observeForever), so my worker is waste?

I run the app, it works fine. I couldn't notice that it blocks the UI or main thread. I suspect it may lag in the future, when api response takes time. So can you explain which thread it will execute?
Any android studio tool is there to see in which thread all code executing?

Comment: "Before api call i will check for the connectivity" -- `WorkManager` can do that for you automatically, before starting your `Worker`. "If i use "Dispatchers.Main" inside "Worker", then my api call will happen in Main thread? " -- yes. "If it runs in main thread, then my usage of worker is of no use?" -- it has issues. "so it is not allowing me to use "Dispatchers.IO"(becoz observeForever)" -- then perhaps you should not be using `observeForever()`. After all, your `Worker` is not working forever.

Comment: Why did you decide to make it a worker in the first place? The only thing this worker does is to register an observer and then it immediately finishes. It does not really do anything in the background.

Comment: @broot But here it says "WorkManager automatically calls Worker.doWork() on a background thread." https://developer.android.com/topic/libraries/architecture/workmanager/advanced/worker

Comment: Yes, it calls `doWork()` in the background thread, then you immediately jump to main thread again, you register observer and you finish `doWork()` just milliseconds after it started. At least this is what I think happens here. You don't do any calculations or network operations inside this background thread. I think this is effectively the same as just calling `observerForever()` from any other place, without the worker at all.